# How to conditionally add or remove classes to dom node based on range slider value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match the "output" of products to a slider range value. My checkboxes work, but not the slider.

See this **codepen** *(select Stratocaster Pickups under second select box)*:

[Codepen!](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/mdVaoqe)

I'm not sure the best way to do this, but my thinking was to assign each product an output number, between 4-10, and use the range value to match. Upon match, the "product cards" will show, and hide when not matched.

So far, I have a function that "deconstructs" the Pickup Group Object:

```
function defineCards(pickups) {
    let pickupInfo = Object.values(pickups);

    for (i = 0; i < pickupInfo.length; i++) {
      let name = pickupInfo[i].name;
      let output = pickupInfo[i].output;
      let look = pickupInfo[i].look;
      let design = pickupInfo[i].design;
```

From which I build "cards" to house the data and dynamically populate each card with the object values. Important part is the Output section:

```
let ab = document.createElement("div");
    ab.classList.add("finalOutput");
    let puOutput = parseInt(output, 10);
    ab.innerHTML = puOutput;
    a.appendChild(ab);
```

**Slider:**

The broken part is the slider. It automatically adds the class of 'hide' to all of my cards at once. I've tried `console.log(value, num)`, and even if they match, the hide class does not go away.

Also, I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this or not. There may be a better way. Full code is in codepen.

Here's the code for the slider:

```
let slider = document.querySelector("#outputSlider"); //Selects slider
    slider.oninput = function () {
      let value = Math.floor(slider.value / 10); //takes 40 - 100 and divides by 10
      let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".pickup-result");

      let cardOutputs = document.querySelectorAll(".finalOutput"); // selects the output in cards

      cardOutputs.forEach(function (num) {
        console.log(value, num);
        if (value != num) {
          cards.forEach(function (card) {
            card.classList.add("hide"); // add the hide class to the card if it they don't match.
          });
        } else if (value == num) {
          cards.forEach(function (card) {
            card.classList.remove("hide"); // remove the hide class of the card if they match.
          });
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

**Edit:**
Now I see what is happening, but don't know how to fix it.

The problem is here:

```
let cardOutputs = document.querySelectorAll(".finalOutput")

cardOutputs.forEach(function (num) {
console.log(num)
}
```

It returns a console log of `4 6 8 5` when I need **each card** `num` to compare to the `value`. How could I do that?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a Number `value` with the DOM element `num`. To fix this just convert `num` to a Number before you make all of your comparisons so right above the line:

`console.log(value, num);`

add

`num = Number(num.innerHTML);`

EDIT as per the request in the comments: To reveal only the matches between the slider value and the final output of the cards, use the same logic above to determine a match and then target the cards to be hidden or revealed depending on the content of their 'finalOutput'. Change your slider code block to this:

```js
let slider = document.querySelector("#outputSlider");
slider.oninput = function () {
    let value = Math.floor(slider.value / 10);
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".pickup-result");
    let cardOutputs = document.querySelectorAll(".finalOutput");
    let match = -1;
    cardOutputs.forEach(function (oCard) {
        if (value == Number(oCard.innerHTML)) {
            match = value;
        }
    });
    if (match >= 0) {
        cards.forEach((card) => {
            const finalOutputDiv = card.querySelectorAll(".finalOutput");
            const id = Number(finalOutputDiv[0].innerText);
            if (id != match) {
                card.classList.add("hide");
            } else {
                card.classList.remove("hide");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Two key things are now happening here when the slider value changes:

1. loop through the displayed cards and set a value for the match variable if a match is made between a displayed card and the slider value.
2. loop through all cards and if a cards 'finalOuput' value is equal to the value of the match variable, reveal the card by removing the `hide` class from its class list, OTHERWISE hide the card by adding the `hide` class to its class list.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. However, it removes the `hide` class on each at once, not by their output, for instance, each model has a different output, how would I change the code to remove the `hide` class when the slider value = 5 and the pickup value = 5, but keep others hidden until the value changes, etc.?

Comment: They all start off revealed so your request is a bit confusing. You want all the non-matches to be hidden when the slider value matches with the output value of a pickup?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but yes, that's exactly what I want. Check the edit on the original post, I believe it has something to do with logging all of the card outputs at once, and not comparing them all to the value individually.

Comment: Allright the answer should fit your needs now. So you can learn, I will leave you to fixing the bug where the cards don't hide themselves until a match from the slider is made. Hint: cards should be hidden when initially displayed. Also you may want to hide the 'finalOutput' values in the cards from the user since you are essentially using that content as an ID and th user doesnt need to know about all that. Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! This is a huge help. Now I have the challenge of connecting the slider result to the checkbox results. Thanks again.

Comment: if I wanted to create a "fuzzy match", like a range of numbers that would define a match, how would you approach it?

Comment: You would need to post that as seperate question.